# excel: use keyboard to move column in data validation mode

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

Usually in excel, when we press the "->" in keyboard, the cell will move from "A1" to "B1". However, it does not work on a drop-down list.

I create this drop-down list by data validation. When I press "->", nothing happen. I have to use mouse to click it every times, it is trouble. Is there any way, or any key, to let me move to new cell?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question in details.  Since it's seems to be confusing :(

Comment: Done. You can take a look. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use Alt+DownArrow to view the DV List on DV cells.  After that use Up and Down arrow to cycle through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your drop-down box on a worksheet, you are right that it doesn't work.

Although you may have lined the drop-down box with the cells around it, it is an object sitting *over* the cell, when you push -> (the right arrow?) or the tab button the selection will go to the next cell, which is under the drop-down box.

The only way to get focus onto the drop down box is to click on it, from there you can use up and down keys to change selection and enter to select an item. After selection focus is given back to the selected cell in the worksheet.

You have tagged this question as 'vba' so to that end what you could do (although it may be a little excessive) is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Replace(Target.Address, "$", "") = "C2" Then
    UserForm1.Show 1
End If
End Sub
```

The above code is placed with the required sheet, if the selection is equal to `C2` then a UserForm opens, within that you could build the selection that are keyboard compatible so you don't need to reach for the mouse.